# I'm a measure of both distance and volume. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> Intact, I'm hard and solid
>
> Broken down, kind of habitat
>
> In repetition, I can help
>
> If moving, I can stop

What am I?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Might you be…

> a block?

I'm a measure of distance

> "I need to walk three blocks to my nearest subway station"

and volume.

> two blocks of chocolate

Intact, I'm hard and solid

> a block of, say, stone tends to be pretty hard

Broken down, kind of habitat

> I live in a block of flats

In repetition, I can help

> It's easier to manage a lot of data if you break it down into blocks.

If moving, I can stop

> by blocking the way

Comment: If indeed that is the answer, for the explanation of volume you can add your answer's 3-dimensional shape as being a unit of volume

Comment: Sounds really like Minecraft blocks. The only thing not really fitting is the last clue.

Comment: Congratulations, this is the answer I was looking for. Though in explanations, repetition part was more like a block you create to draw patterns repeatedly. You got everything else correct.

Comment: I did come across the term "block" to measure distance when I worked in the USA. I have not heard it used in Asia or Europe

Answer (score 5):

**Biiiiig** stretch:

I'm a measure of both distance and volume. What am I?

> A stone is a measure of weight and 'a stones throw' is a lazy un-specific measure of distance

Intact, I'm hard and solid

> Literally; check.

Broken down, kind of habitat

> A Pound is both a unit of a stone and a place where animals live; ...check?

In repetition, I can help

> Pounding multiple times?  Multiple Pounds (as in currency)?  Uncertain...

If moving, I can stop

> A moving stone can stop...

Comment: "Broken down, kind of habitat" could refer to shingle/pebbles/gravel, maybe? Or even sand (deserts) for that matter.

Answer (score 4):

Could you be...

> One

Intact, I'm hard and solid

> Hard One and Solid One are both common (?) idioms

Broken down, kind of habitat

> One can be broken into Quarters, which is another word for habitat

In repetition, I can help

> 111 is a UK help line

If moving, I can stop

> Not sure about this...

Comment: Nice try, it could fit if not for the last clue.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not, because this answer is based on a running joke from an old group of friends, but could you be:

> A Hamster?

A measure of both distance and volume:

> There was a group of my friends a while back that had a running joke that hamsters were a universal unit: They have an average weight, volume, length, speed, temperature, and so on. With a bit of creativity, any unit could be measured with hamsters!
>  I realize that this is true of basically any living thing, but hamsters were what we decided to use as our universal unit, so that's what I'm sticking with.

Intact, I'm hard and solid

> This one doesn't really work :(
> But hamster teeth are in fact quite hard and sharp, so there's that.

Broken down, kind of habitat

> Like all mammals, hamsters have a wide variety of microbes living in them. And, if a hamster were to be "broken down" (i.e. decomposed), it would be a kind of habitat for whatever bacteria or fungus were to consume it.

In repetition, I can help

> Hamsters are very good at repetitive activities, such as running in a hamster wheel.

If moving, I can stop

> In a hamster wheel, hamsters can come to a stop, and bring the spinning wheel to a stop.

Comment: When I took an AI class a couple of semesters back, we had to learn and use a programming language called Scheme, Some of our projects took quite a long time, but the average was around 8 hours. We started using it as a measure of time, i.e. "my math homework took half a Scheme project to complete"

Comment: I doubt if that is the answer, but it certainly gave me a good laugh!

Comment: Interesting answer.

Answer (score 1):

Much is based on [balpha's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/58208/34836), here is mine, stretched as and when needed:

> It could be a cell

As,

> A cell is used a measuring means in certain situations as jail/mobile communications and also a cell is a measure for expressing few scenarios in biology/any physical construction.

Intact I am hard and solid

> A physical cell(a battery/jail room) is hard and solid.

Broken down kinda habitat

> Biological cells when broken (divided) leads to new life or when jail walls are broken - leads to a place where people can live in

In repetition I can help

> In repetition they become cells and are of much help than a single one

If moving, can stop

> Not sure of this, though !

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an obvious answer.. but a bit of a stretch.

Are you...

> a meter

I'm a measure of both distance and volume

> meter as a distance and a cubic meter as volume

Intact, I'm hard and solid

> a gas/electric/water meter on your house is hard and solid in the literal sense

Broken down, kind of habitat

> could you say... a lack of working parking meters would be a habitat for lawlessness? As in people parking without paying. (this one is quite a stretch)

In repetition, I can help

> Meters in music

If moving, I can stop

> a parking meter will stop moving once it runs out of money

Answer (score 1):

I thought about

> bars

I'm a measure of both distance and volume

> On my way home in the weekend the bars (pubs) qualifies for distance and a bar(pub) is also a volume. Also volume can mean the loudness of a song.

Intact, I'm hard and solid

> a bar (rod) is hard and solid

Broken down, kind of habitat

> Bars (pubs) are all kinds of habitat, and people tends to break down there...

In repetition, I can help

> In a song, bars (of a rhymme) are really helpful

If moving, I can stop

> When the song ends, the bars are over

Comment: Could you make these points clearer - ‘distance and volume’, ‘habitat’ and ‘moving’?